# Loop not working and produces IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

Why is the first one working and the other not?

```
for (int v=0; v< student1.size();v++) {
    readLine = student1.get(v);

    if (readLine.contains(sbB)){

        while(!(readLine1.contains(sbA) || readLine1.contains(sbC) || readLine1.contains(sbD) )){

            readLine1 = student1.get(ii);
            if(readLine1.contains("Homework ")){
                String[] tokens = readLine1.split(": "); st1marksHwB.add(tokens[1]);summHw = summHw + Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);}
            if (readLine1.contains("Exam ")){
                String[] tokens = readLine1.split(": "); st1marksExB.add(tokens[1]);summEx = summEx + Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);;}
            ii++;}}}   
double avSt1B = summHw*0.2 + summEx*0.8; summHw=0;summEx=0;

//Stundent 1 Subject C---------------------------------------------------
for (int v=0; v< student1.size();v++) {
      readLine = student1.get(v);

    if (readLine.contains(sbC)){

        while(!(readLine1.contains(sbA) || readLine1.contains(sbB) || readLine1.contains(sbD) )){

            readLine1 = student1.get(ii);
                if(readLine1.contains("Homework ")){
                    String[] tokens = readLine1.split(": "); st1marksHwC.add(tokens[1]);summHw = summHw + Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);}
                if (readLine1.contains("Exam ")){
                    String[] tokens = readLine1.split(": "); st1marksExC.add(tokens[1]);summEx = summEx + Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);;}
                ii++;}}}
double avSt1C = summHw*0.2 + summEx*0.8; summHw=0;summEx=0;
```

Comment: i been here long enough, mah man ! Imma know that u be doing this homework sh!t, yeah ? so imma ask u to temme clearly whatcha done. Post them `stack trace` xD and format that code.

Comment: Scuse me? Plain English for me buddy... How do I format the code?

Comment: Ok, just select all your code and press `CTRL + K` xD

Comment: can u paste ur full code.

Comment: What do you mean by "working" and "not working"? Is it the for loops that aren't working? Some if statements?

Comment: Sure but is way Long... I will paste

Comment: It returs the exception, just as it runs the second For()...

Comment: Its difficult to detect the issue from half code or paste the error stack trace

Comment: Before you go posting all your code, have you tried resetting `ii` as selva suggests below, it definitely looks like that's your problem

Comment: Are you asking us to play spot-the-difference with your code (if yes, that's not particularly appropriate as a [so] question; if no, I don't really understand what you're asking)? You really should be wrapping that in a method so you don't have to duplicate code. And please post a [Minimal, **Complete**, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'd like to help but this is really hard to understand. Can you fix the formatting first? It's also difficult to know what the error is without knowing what goes inside student1 and what ii goes to. Additionally a quick summary of your program would help a lot.

Comment: Well it is solved... it WAS the ii valuer passing on... Sorry for my poor formating and all. I have just started and do not now well how to use the site..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you increase the value of `ii` in the first for-loop using `ii++` . 
Then the last increased value of `ii` is passed to second for-loop.

Comment: Of course it is... Cheers mate!